# found for loop has 14 operations and map method has 9 operations

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs, time-complexity, space-complexity

- i am trying to understand the complexity of map method in js.
- can you tell me which one is better one.
- since in some of my react code I see people using map method http://jsfiddle.net/jhudson8/135oo6f8/.
- not sure when to use map method and for loop.
- I am providing two codes below.
- using this example I calculated complexity https://github.com/andyttran/guide_to_algorithms#1c-analyze-line-by-line
  **- and found for loop has 14 operations and map method has 9 operations.**
- in the coments below I have given value one for e ch operation.
- can you tell me whether I have done it correctly

```or-tag-here
for loop

var cars =[
            {'toyota' : 'corolla', 'honda' : 'civic'},
            {'toyota' : 'corolla1', 'honda' : 'civic1'},
            {'toyota' : 'corolla2', 'honda' : 'civic2'},
            {'toyota' : 'corolla3', 'honda' : 'civic3'},
    ];
var names = []; //names = 1, [] = 1
for(var i=0; i< cars.length; i++) {  //  for = 1 , var i = 1, =0 = 1, < = 1, cars.length = 1, i++ = 1
    names.push(cars[i].toyota); //names = 1, push = 1, cars[i] = 1, toyota = 1
}
console.log(names); has an array access and then a printing to the console, so thats 2 operations
total = 14


map method js

var cars =[
            {'toyota' : 'corolla', 'honda' : 'civic'},
            {'toyota' : 'corolla1', 'honda' : 'civic1'},
            {'toyota' : 'corolla2', 'honda' : 'civic2'},
            {'toyota' : 'corolla3', 'honda' : 'civic3'},
    ];

var mapValues = cars.map(function(animal){ //mapvalues = 1, cars = 1, map= 1, function= 1
    return animal.toyota; //return = 1, animal = 1, toyota = 1
});
console.log(mapValues); // has an array access and then a printing to the console, so thats 2 operations
total = 9
```

Comment: I don't think there's "better" - `map` is not fully implemented in all exotic browsers (think mobiles..) and requires a polyfil, if you want to avoid the polyfill you use a for loop, most modern apps will use map with a polyfill though.

Comment: The `map` method is useful when you want to transform __every__ index of an array via a given function and return that new array. In theory this will just loop through the array (similar to your for loop) and reassign the indexes (in practice it's probably more complex). The `map` method can also be a bit more concise and is a more functional way of doing things. E.g. `cars.map(animal => animal.toyota)` is a very concise way of doing your map. Also `map` is supported pretty much everywhere as it's a part of the ES5 spec (http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5).

Comment: @Patrick https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example#Browser_compatibility support seems fine to me

Comment: I'm not sure what mobile browsers you're referring to @Patrick.

Comment: IE8 is an obvious catch there, I also remembered(incorrectly, i guess) that some mobiles do not support it. In some companies support for IE8 is (still) a must.

Comment: You say that the map method has less operations, but you're looking at it from a surface level. Map has it's own internal operations so it isn't really just one operation. Regardless, it's probably insignificant for deciding between the two. Using a for loop gives you complete control ( you can skip or break out of the loop early) while using the map method will always map every single item in the array and like @varbrad said it is more concise

Comment: It's very difficult to work out as it is a native method that must be implemented within the JavaScript environment, so Chrome's `map` method may internally work completely different to how Firefox's does, and can subsuquently have a totally different 'complexity' as you put it. (Also, please don't post loads of comments with the same message)

Comment: @varbrad so in interview if they ask me to find the complexity of two codes what should I need to say

Comment: It would depend upon what they meant by 'complexity'! There is no one answer really, especially without knowing more about exactly what measure of 'complexity' there were using.

Comment: @varbrad for both space and time complexity

Comment: In terms of the space & time complexity for your given functions (Both of which basically do the same thing, just one with a `for loop` and the other using `Array.map`, all you are doing is creating a new array of size `n` (Where `n` is the size of the original array) and you are doing that just once for both. As such, space and time complexity of both approaches can be considered the same.

Answer (score 1):

The way you count "operations" is really arbitrary: some of them will "cost" a lot more than others.

For instance, you count `i++` as one operation, but someone might say it consists of 5 operations:

- Read the value of i
- Keep that value in memory
- Calculate i+1
- Update i with that calculated value
- Return the memorised value

... and then there still is no indication of which of these operations is more costly than the others. This way of comparing different algorithms will not bring you much.

What is important with calculating time and space complexities is the *order* of magnitude. Imagine `cars.length` is not 4, but one million. Then it really is not significant whether the operations outside the loop are 4, 6, 9, 11, ... What is important is that these operations are the same in number whether your input array is small or large. So they represent a *constant* number of operations, i.e. they have *O(1)* time complexity.

The same reasoning goes for the loop. It is about order of magnitude. If the body of the loop has 4 or 5 operations, that just means the total number of operations for the complete loop is *4n* or *5n*. In both cases the order of magnitude is *n* (as opposed to *n²*, or *nlogn*, ...). That is what is important when speaking of time and space complexities.

So, in conclusion, both the old `for` loop and array methods like `map`, `forEach`, `reduce`, ... have a time complexity of *O(n)*.

Comment: thanks for your reply....did not understand this line...as opposed to n², or nlogn, ...)   ---> can you tell in detail :(

Comment: Those are unrelated to the loop, but other algorithms have such time complexities (like sort algorithms). I just wanted to give examples of time complexities that would be considered different. But 4n or 5n both have the same time complexity. n.logn would not be considered the same. That is just an example.